# Add items to layout in dynamic way

Tags: android

I want to add buttons to layout from code, but in specific way. All buttons should be added in horizontal orientation in one line, but when last button is too long, should be put in next line. How can I do that? There is any custom control to do that?

Comment: you can make use of gridview. and add/remove items whenever u want by just calling notifydatasetchanged method from its adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a certain width to your button and calculate every time if there is enough space to add a new one, the container could be a `RelativeLayout`, use the relative position to control the new line issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
   LinearLayout my_root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root);
    LinearLayout A = new LinearLayout(this);
    A.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    A.addView(view1);
    A.addView(view2);
    A.addView(view3);
    my_root.addView(A);
```

view1,view2,view3 are your textviews.. easily created programmatically

Hope above code will help you.

Let me know if you need more help in same.